# Is possible to create an generic constrained method?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010, constraints, delphi-xe2

I created the following simple class in my code and I get *"TObject is not a valid constraint"* error message.

```
  TTest = class
    class function Test<T:TObject>(Dummy: integer): string;
  end;
  ... 
  class function TTeste.Teste<T>(Dummy: integer): string;
  begin
    Result := 'Compiled';
  end;
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is this possible? (You can include option available on later versions than D2010, since we'll receive our XE2 licenses in the next 2 weeks).

Comment: First hit when searching for "generic constraints delphi" answers this.

Comment: Almost sleepless night... I'm not normally that lazy.. I simply not remembered to do it. Shame on me ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the `class` constraint:

```
TTest = class
  class function Test<T:class>(Dummy: integer): string;
end;
```

It might not only accept normal classes, but also interfaces with that constraint(in C# it does, and Delphi generics imitate C# generics).

Comment: This answer is correct. But where is the semantic difference between `T:class` and `T:TObject`? Interfaces are not accepted and yield error `E2511`.